# How to run a function when another function is complete?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a Angular function:

```
$scope.addMovie = function(movie){
  addMovieRecord(movie)
  addMovieCredits(movie)
}
```

And two Javascript functions:

```
var addMovieRecord = function (movie){

  createMovie.create({
    id:             $scope.movieListID.id,
    release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
    imdb_rating:    $scope.movieImdbRating.imdbRating,
    title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
    image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
    movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id,
    backdrop:       $scope.movieListID.backdrop_path,
    overview:       $scope.movieCredits.overview
  })

}
```

And

```
var addMovieCredits = function (movie){

  movieService.loadMovies().then(function(response) {
  $scope.moviesCheck = response.data;

}
```

So when I run the `$scope.addMovie` function it should first fire the `addMovieRecord` function which creates a movie record. Then the `createMovie` should fire the `addMovieCredits` to load all the records.

But that doesn't happen. `addMovieCredits` returns all the records, except the one that just has been created. So it looks like the order isn't correct,

If I fire the `addMovieCredits (movie)` directly after the create function it does load all the records,

```
createMovie.create({
  id:             $scope.movieListID.id,
  release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
  imdb_rating:    $scope.movieImdbRating.imdbRating,
  title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
  image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
  movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id,
  backdrop:       $scope.movieListID.backdrop_path,
  overview:       $scope.movieCredits.overview
}).then(addMovieCredits(movie));
```

But that's not what I want. I want to load the movie records after the add function has been completed.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

*** update ***

This is the createMovie service,

```
app.factory('createMovie', ['$http', function($http){
  return{
    create: function(movie){
      return $http.post('/movies.json', movie);
    }
  };
}]);
```

Comment: You are invoking the `loadMovies(movie)` function before `createMovie.create` is done. You should pass a reference or an anonymous function which executes `loadMovies(movie)`.

Comment: As much as i understood your code, you can write ``}).then(loadMovies);``

Comment: @styopdev you mean after the createMovie.create call? Isn't that exactly what I have in my example?

Comment: @PeterBoomsma there is difference between ``}).then(loadMovies)`` and ``}).then(function() { loadMovies(movie) })`` first code pass function as param the second one (code from example) will invoked immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Considering the `createMovie` is a `$resource` object then you can do like this:</strike>

(What I'm not sure in your code is that `createMovie` is a `$scope` function and also you are calling `create` on the `createMovie`? There should be some naming conflict)

```
var addMovieRecord = function (movie){
  // return from here which should be a promise
  return createMovie.create({
    id:             $scope.movieListID.id,
    release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
    imdb_rating:    $scope.movieImdbRating.imdbRating,
    title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
    image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
    movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id,
    backdrop:       $scope.movieListID.backdrop_path,
    overview:       $scope.movieCredits.overview
  });
}
```

Then, use the returned promise

```
$scope.addMovie = function(movie) {
  // or try "success" instead of "then" (may vary based on your Angular's version)
  addMovieRecord(movie).then(function() {
      addMovieCredits(movie)
  });
}
```

**Update**

The syntax `.then(loadMovies(movie));` in your question should also work except there is a problem. The `then` function expects a function but you are passing the function after you are immediately calling it by using `()` in the `loadMovie` syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I must admit I did edit some naming for this question, so it's not 100% copy of my actual code, but I'm going to look into it. I'll try to work your suggestion in my project.

Comment: I've tried to work with the code but it keeps returning an error `Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`. Which points to `addMovieRecord(movie).then(function()`

Comment: Okay, can you post what does `createMovie.create({` returns in your code?

Comment: I've edited my question to represent the naming better. Also I've added the `createMovie` service function to the question.

Comment: Sure, I've modified the answer. I was assuming that you are using `$resource` but you are using `$http`. So the updated solution should work.

Comment: Whether I use `.then` or `.succes` it still returns `Cannot read property 'succes' of undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This.

```
$scope.createMovie = function(movie){
  addMovie(movie).$promise.then(function(){
      loadMovies(movie)
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
movieService.loadMovies().then(function(response) {
$scope.moviesCheck = response.data;}
```

you call this service one time at the bigining of the controller
and after you add a movie every time you click at the button who invoque AddMovie function passing the list of movies .

```
<button ng-click="AddMovie(moviesCheck)"></button>   


 $scope.addMovie = function (moviesCheck){

      var movie ={
        id:             $scope.movieListID.id,
        release_date:   releaseNL.release_date,
        imdb_rating:    $scope.movieImdbRating.imdbRating,
        title:          $scope.movieListID.original_title,
        image:          $scope.movieListID.poster_path,
        movie_id:       $scope.movieListID.id,
        backdrop:       $scope.movieListID.backdrop_path,
        overview:       $scope.movieCredits.overview
      }

    movieService.AddMovie(Movie) ; 

// you call the service who add the movie at database
then you add the movie at the existing list in the view

    moviesCheck.push(Movie); 

}
```